# How to sign a JWT with a private key (pem) in CryptoJS?

Tags: javascript, jwt, postman, cryptojs

I am trying to create a signed JWT in postman with the following code

```
function base64url(source) {
    // Encode in classical base64
    encodedSource = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(source);

    // Remove padding equal characters
    encodedSource = encodedSource.replace(/=+$/, '');

    // Replace characters according to base64url specifications
    encodedSource = encodedSource.replace(/\+/g, '-');
    encodedSource = encodedSource.replace(/\//g, '_');

    return encodedSource;
}

function addIAT(request) {
    var iat = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 257;
    data.iat = iat;
    return data;
}


var header = {
    "typ": "JWT",
    "alg": "HS256"
};

var data = {
    "fname": "name",
    "lname": "name",
    "email": "email@domain.com",
    "password": "abc123$"
};

data = addIAT(data);

var secret = 'myjwtsecret';

// encode header
var stringifiedHeader = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(JSON.stringify(header));
var encodedHeader = base64url(stringifiedHeader);

// encode data
var stringifiedData = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
var encodedData = base64url(stringifiedData);

// build token
var token = encodedHeader + "." + encodedData;

// sign token
var signature = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(token, secret);
signature = base64url(signature);
var signedToken = token + "." + signature;

postman.setEnvironmentVariable("payload", signedToken);
```

Code taken from https://gist.github.com/corbanb/db03150abbe899285d6a86cc480f674d .

I've been trying to input the PEM as the secret but does not work. Also can't find any HmacSHA256 overload that takes a PEM.

How can that be done?

Comment: Did you manage to get it working in the end?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The mention of postman changed this. I have a solution for you, but it's not exactly a clean way by any mean.

You'll need to create a request that you will need to execute whenever you open postman. Go as follows:

[image: Side-loading jsrsasign-js]

The purpose of this request is to side-load `jsrsasign-js` and storing it in a global Postman variable.

Once this is done, you can then use this content elsewhere. For every request you need a RSA256 JWT signature, the following pre-request script will update a variable (here, `token`) with the token:

```
var navigator = {};
var window = {};
eval(pm.globals.get("jsrsasign-js"));

function addIAT(request) {
    var iat = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 257;
    data.iat = iat;
    return data;
}

var header = {"alg" : "RS256","typ" : "JWT"};
var data = {
    "fname": "name",
    "lname": "name",
    "email": "email@domain.com",
    "password": "abc123$"
};

data = addIAT(data);

var privateKey = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- \
MIIBOQIBAAJAcrqH0L91/j8sglOeroGyuKr1ABvTkZj0ATLBcvsA91/C7fipAsOn\
RqRPZr4Ja+MCx0Qvdc6JKXa5tSb51bNwxwIDAQABAkBPzI5LE+DuRuKeg6sLlgrJ\
h5+Bw9kUnF6btsH3R78UUANOk0gGlu9yUkYKUkT0SC9c6HDEKpSqILAUsXdx6SOB\
AiEA1FbR++FJ56CEw1BiP7l1drM9Mr1UVvUp8W71IsoZb1MCIQCKUafDLg+vPj1s\
HiEdrPZ3pvzvteXLSuniH15AKHEuPQIhAIsgB519UysMpXBDbtxJ64jGj8Z6/pOr\
NrwV80/EEz45AiBlgTLZ2w2LjuNIWnv26R0eBZ+M0jHGlD06wcZK0uLsCQIgT1kC\
uNcDTERjwEbFKJpXC8zTLSPcaEOlbiriIKMnpNw=\
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----";

var sHeader = JSON.stringify(header);
var sPayload = JSON.stringify(data);

var sJWT = KJUR.jws.JWS.sign(header.alg, sHeader, sPayload, privateKey);

pm.variables.set('token', sJWT);
```

In order:

- I define mock `window` and `navigator` objects as `jsrsasign-js` needs them.
- I then `eval()` the content of what we fetched earlier in order to rehydrate everything
- The rest of your code is simple usage of `jsrsasign-js`. Your token info is there, and I've defined a private key there. You can change this or use an environment variable; it's just there for demo purposes. I then simply use the rehydrated library to sign it, and set the variable to the value of the signed JWT.

---

A `PEM`, as you refer to it, is a container format specifying a combination of public and/or private key. You're using it to sign using `HMAC-SHA256`, which operates on a **shared** secret. This obviously isn't going to work (unless you take the poor man's approach and use your public key as the shared secret).

Fortunately enough, there are other signature methods defined in the RFCs. For instance, there is a way to sign using `RSA`, and a very convenient way of defining a public key as a [JSON web key](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7517) (`JWK`). We're going to be leveraging both.

I've generated a key pair for testing, they're named `out` and `out.pub`. Generation tool is `genrsa` (and as such, they're an RSA keypair).

In order to sign, we're going to have to change a few things:

- We're changing algorithms from `HS256` to `RS256`, as explained above
- We're going to need a new library to do the signing itself, as `crypto-js` does not support asymmetric key crypto. We'll fall back to the native `crypto` module, though there are pure-JS alternatives

The code:

```
var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");
var keyFileContent = require("fs").readFileSync("./out");
var pubkey = require("fs").readFileSync("./out.pub");
var base64url = require("base64url");
var nJwt = require("njwt");
function addIAT(request) {
    var iat = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 257;
    data.iat = iat;
    return data;
}


var header = {
    "typ": "JWT",
    "alg": "RS256"
};

var data = {
    "fname": "name",
    "lname": "name",
    "email": "email@domain.com",
    "password": "abc123$"
};

data = addIAT(data);

// encode header
var stringifiedHeader = JSON.stringify(header);
var encodedHeader = base64url(stringifiedHeader);

// encode data
var stringifiedData = JSON.stringify(data);
var encodedData = base64url(stringifiedData);

// build token
var token = encodedHeader + "." + encodedData;

// sign token
var signatureAlg = require("crypto").createSign("sha256");
signatureAlg.update(token);
var signature = signatureAlg.sign(keyFileContent);
signature = base64url(signature);
var signedToken = token + "." + signature;

console.log(signedToken);

// Verify
var verifier = new nJwt.Verifier();
verifier.setSigningAlgorithm('RS256');
verifier.setSigningKey(pubkey);
verifier.verify(signedToken, function() {
  console.log(arguments);
});
```

And that's it! It's quite literally that simple, although I would not recommend rewriting the `sign()` function from `crypto` from scratch. Leave it to a library that has had thorough inspection by the community, and crypto is pretty serious business.

Comment: I cant use that in Postman. Postman is refusing to load base64url and njwt modules, for some reason it loads crypto-js

Comment: Postman's sandbox only allows some node modules https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/postman_sandbox_api_reference/ (`crypto-js` is the only crypto related module)

Comment: That's going to be really fun then, as cryptojs doesn't support RSA.

Comment: In other words without creating a custom javascript code for running this, there is no way?

Comment: @Aleksandar There might be a way. I'm testing something which is  slightly hackish but will work for you, I think.

Comment: @Aleksandar it actually works! It's clunky, but it works. Sideloading `jsrsasign-js` has never been more fun

Comment: I keep getting `undefined: undefined` when trying `KJUR.jws.JWS.sign("RS256", sHeader, unsignedInput, privateKey);` but I'm trying to sign a Google Service Account key so I just need to sign a section and build the JWT myself (idk if all JWT follow the base64header.base64claimset.base64signature format)

Comment: @KyleCalica-St You did follow the instructions, including the pre-load request to get `jsrsasign-js` in the state table of postman, right? As for your question itself, all `JWT`s are compose of (at least) 3 base64 section delimited by dots.

Comment: Yeah I did a pre-load request. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59383521/postman-pre-request-script-to-create-jwt-for-google-service-account 
I can also share a link to my collection: 
https://www.getpostman.com/collections/5545d5302f8544223e59

Comment: Seems like this is the issue: https://medium.com/@jkohne/hi-klaasjan-tukker-im-trying-to-get-the-library-import-and-eval-to-work-for-jsrsasign-c0c457ddd23f 

But trying to see how I might have pre-loaded jsrsasign wrong? I've added a link to my collection above.

Comment: looking at the minified code i can kinda recreate it with JWSJS but then i have trouble trying to create the signature which was the reason for using this library ...

Comment: solved it: Private Key had whitespace characters in it. They need to have the key formatted and without escaped whitespace.

Comment: Published my Postman Collection for anyone else who has problems and needs to see it: https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/8140651/SWECYFyf?version=latest

Comment: That's one of the most underrated answers here at SO, even with the bounty given. ) I ended up with slightly different approach of handling PK, making it a part of environment setup (and thus avoiding the need to cut it from pre-req script).

Comment: This epic answer worked for me without any changes other than to use a cdn for the library: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsrsasign/8.0.20/jsrsasign-all-min.js

Comment: @amurrell Don't hesitate to suggest an edit :-)

Comment: I had to update the "setup" request wit the url https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kjur/jsrsasign/master/jsrsasign-all-min.js
And it worked like a charm. Thanks a lot!