POSTMAN - Docusign - Get an access token with JWT Authentication
I am trying to create a JWT token to get an access token for docusign API.
This is the documentation I am following.
I created a pre-request script to create the assertion in Postman. I created three environment variables in POSTMAN.

Public Key,
Private Key
jsrsasign library

I also tried to get the jsrsasign library at runtime, though that is not working for me.
Here is the pre-request script.
// Loading the jsrsasign library into Postman Sandbox
var navigator = {}; // Fake a navigator object for the lib
var window = {}; // Fake a window object for the lib


if (!pm.environment.get("jsrsasign")) {
    pm.sendRequest("https://kjur.github.io/jsrsasign/jsrsasign-all-min.js", function(err, res) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log("setting jrassign");
            pm.environment.set("jsrsasign", res.text());
        }
    })
}

eval(pm.environment.get("jsrsasign")); // Import JavaScript jsrsasign

var timestamp = new Date(); // The current time in milliseconds
var issuedAtTimeSeconds = timestamp / 1000;
var expirationTimeSeconds = timestamp / 1000 + 3600;

// Create header and payload objects
var header = { "typ": "JWT", "alg": "RS256" };
var payload = {
    "iss": "<integration key>",
    "sub": "<subscription guid>",
    "aud": "account-d.docusign.com",
    "iat": Math.ceil(issuedAtTimeSeconds),
    "exp": Math.ceil(issuedAtTimeSeconds)+3600,
    "scope":"signature impersonation"
};

// Create the encoded assertion
var assertion = KJUR.jws.JWS.sign("RS256", JSON.stringify(header), JSON.stringify(payload), pm.environment.get("publickey"), pm.environment.get("privatekey"));

// Set the assertion as a request header
pm.request.headers.add({ key: "Authorization", value: "Bearer " + assertion });

The error I keep getting in the POSTMAN console is
ReferenceError: KJUR is not defined

The postman documentation for JWT is very specific, did you see https://developers.docusign.com/tools/postman/ and looked the JWT section?

@InbarGazit I have read this documentation and am able to generate the JWT using jwt.io and get an assertion. My question is about generating the jwt in POSTMAN without having to go out of the POSTMAN environment.

ok, which documentation did you follow to do it inside postman? Docusign doesnt' document it so I am curious, maybe I can take a look

I followed a post on stackoverflow. It was trying to generate a jwt for a different service.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59383521/postman-pre-request-script-to-create-jwt-for-google-service-account

So the issue I am experiencing is that the contents of the jsrsasign won't load onto the local variable. So I copied the contents of the script from
http://kjur.github.io/jsrsasign/jsrsasign-latest-all-min.js
into the initial value and current value.
Once I had done that the script was finally able to reference KJUR. I am now able to get an access token in POSTMAN.

Just to confirm, this issue has nothing to do with Docusign - is that correct?

It is more about getting a jwt token using a library in postman. My specific issue happened to be a jwt for docusign, the other user had it for google services.
